# Как заставить SVG фигуру кружиться вокруг середины блока?

Tags: css, css3, svg, css-animation

Есть такой  пример:

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
 svg{
  background: orange;
 }
</style>
    <polygon points="50 50, 0 100,  100 100" fill="gray">
   <!--
-->
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate" from="1 1 100" to="100 100 100" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</polygon>
 
</svg>
```

Хочу заставить треугольник крутиться вершиной вокруг середины блока SVG.

Не прошу банального решения за меня, прошу объяснить, как работает система координат

```
from="1 1 100 " 
to="100 100 100"
```

Если я правильно понял, это аналог `@keyframes - CSS`, и если я прав, то правильной ли будет такая конструкция со средними значениями `from="1 1 100 " 50%="50 50 50" to="100 100 100"`

И вообще, в правильном ли я направлении в реализации данной задачи?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

От нуля до 360 градусов вокруг точки (50, 50):

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
 svg{
  background: orange;
 }
</style>
    <polygon points="50 50, 0 100,  100 100" fill="gray">
   <!--
-->
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                          attributeType="XML"
                          type="rotate" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" dur="5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</polygon>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Благодарю, Igor... Час мучился)))))

Answer (score 4):

### CSS решение

В варианте решения SVG при трансформации вращения нужно точно выбрать центр вращения.
В примере выше, легко было найти центр вращения -`50х50`  для квадрата  `100х100`

Но как быть, если нужно найти  центр сложной фигуры SVG?
 Это превращается в непростую задачу при ручном подборе или нужно использовать JS  `bbox`

В CSS есть [`transform-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box) для решения этой задачи. Эта правило CSS избавляет от поиска центра вращения:

- **`transform-box:border-box;`**

Использует центр родительского контейнера. В примере это центр прямоугольника - холст SVG `100x100px`

```html
<style>
.polygon {
transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: border-box;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

:hover.polygon {
 webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
          transform: rotate(720deg);
 }

</style>
<svg id="svg1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
 svg{
  background: orange;
 }
</style>
    <polygon class="polygon" points="50 50, 0 100,  100 100" fill="gray">
 
</polygon>
 
</svg>
```

- **`transform-box:fill-box;`**

Для вращения используется центр прямоугольника, ограничивающего треугольник.

```html
<style>
.polygon {

transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: fill-box;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

:hover.polygon {
 webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
          transform: rotate(720deg);
 }

</style>
<svg id="svg1" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
 svg{
  background: orange;
 }
</style>
    <polygon class="polygon" points="50 50, 0 100,  100 100" fill="gray">
 
</polygon>
 
</svg>
```

- **`transform-box:view-box;`**

Центр вращения находится в середине холста SVG

```html
<style>
.polygon {

transform-origin: center center;
transform-box: view-box;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease-in-out;
          transition:         transform 2s ease-in-out;
}

:hover.polygon {
 webkit-transform: rotate(720deg);
          transform: rotate(720deg);
  }

</style>
<svg  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<style>
 svg{
  background: orange;
 }
</style>
    <polygon class="polygon" points="50 50, 0 100,  100 100" fill="gray"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне очень нравится CSS решение, потому что `animateTransform` работает не везде! Молодец! В закладках наверно держал 1,5 года? :-)

Comment: @Bharata Благодарю, что-то искал, на глаза попалась

Comment: Привет, странно, что ты не видел этого вопроса раньше, я про него и забыл...))) Благодарю.. Хорошее решение...

Comment: @Air Привет Норик! Угу, странно,:) что не видел, так мало вопросов по SVG, обычно 100% просматриваю

Comment: @Alexandr_TT transform-box:fill-box; Для вращения используется центр прямоугольника, ограничивающего треугольник. Центр прямоугольника - это то что окрашено желтым цветом; ограничивающего треугольник как это ?

Comment: @Leks ну представь, см. второй пример, что треугольник вписан в прямоугольник, вот вокруг центра этого прямоугольника происходит вращение.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT вроде как понял

Comment: @Alexandr_TT В чем тогда разница между transform-origin и transform-box ?

Comment: @Leks  `transform-origin` выбирает точку за которую будет вращать `transform-box` - это  контейнер внутри, которого находится фигура. Если `transform-origin:center center` значит контейнер будет вращаться за центр. Если `transform-origin:left top` Значит контейнер будет вращаться вокруг левого верхнего угла

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Вашему другу требуется помощь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1060452/%d0%90%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0/1060459#1060459

Comment: @Alexandr_TT немного разобрался думаю остальное сделает практика ...