# Как сделать анимацию вращения круга в звезде?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation

Как сделать анимацию вращения круга в звезде?

```html
<svg>
 <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="black"
   points="150,0 121,90 198,35 102,35 179,90"/>
   <circle r="15" cx="150" cy="50" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Круг надо разбить на сегменты, иначе не будет видно вращения

`stroke-dasharray="3 2"`
и применить правило

```
transform-origin: center center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
```

Чтобы не искать центр вращения

```css
 #circ {
  stroke:crimson;
  stroke-width:6;
  stroke-dasharray:3 2;
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: rotate_disk 2s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_disk {
   100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
   }
  }
```

```html
<svg>
 <polygon fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="black"
   points="150,0 121,90 198,35 102,35 179,90"/>
   <circle id="circ" r="15" cx="150" cy="50" fill="none"> </circle>
</svg>
```

**Update**

Более подробно о **transform-box: fill-box** с примерами в этом топике

[Как заставить SVG фигуру кружиться вокруг середины блока?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1058524/28748)

Comment: свойство transform-box: fill-box; как понять ?

Comment: transform-origin свойство понятное оно определяет расположения точки относительной которой будет происходит транформация

Comment: @Leks Добавил ссылку на связанный топик, где разобраны все примеры применения `transform-box: fill-box`

Comment: Простите если глупость но, нельзя вложить звезду в "круглый" div и его завращать, не помню нюансов css но там кода строк на пять

Comment: @CoffeJava попробуйте, заодно и вспомните эти 5 строк CSS Новые ответы, только приветствуются, чем больше решений, тем полезней  для всех. По крайней мере от меня + гарантирован, если всё будет норм. :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я правильно понял что transform-origin это центр круга а transform-box: fill-box; это центр svg холста ?

Comment: @Leks Нет, немного не так. `transform-box: fill-box;` - это прямоугольник вокруг окружности  `#circ`; `transform-origin:center center` центр этого прямоугольника. В этом случае центр прямоугольника и центр окружности совпадают.

Answer (score 5):

### На вопрос уже дан ответ, этот топик для души

А вы заметили, что вместо звезды на шапке появилось сердце?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавлю анимацию звезды на старое место, для этого с картинки убираем иконку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Берем звезду из предыдущего ответа и с помощью команд `transform="scale(0.35) translate(56 175)"` уменьшаем и позиционируем звезду.

```html
<svg height="70vh"> 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHM2F.png" width="147px" height="137px" />
  <g transform="scale(0.35) translate(56 175)">
 <polygon  id="star" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" fill="crimson"
   points="150,0 121,90 198,35 102,35 179,90"/>
   <circle id="circ" r="15" cx="150" cy="50" fill="none"/>
   </g> 
   
</svg>
```

Добавляем анимацию вращения:

```css
#star {
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box:fill-box;
 animation: rotate_star 10s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_star {
   100% {transform: rotateZ(360deg);}
    }
```

```html
<svg height="100vh"> 
 <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHM2F.png" width="147px" height="137px" />
  <g transform="scale(0.35) translate(57 176)">
  <circle id="circ" r="50" cx="150" cy="45" fill="none"stroke-width="8" stroke="gold"/>
 <polygon  id="star" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="none" fill="crimson"
   points="150,0 121,90 198,35 102,35 179,90"/>
  
   </g> 
   
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Второе очевидное решение - двигать `stroke-dashoffset`:

```html
<svg id="test" 
   viewBox=-300,-300,600,600 >

 <circle 
    stroke-dasharray="31.415 31.415" 
    r=100 
    stroke=red  
    stroke-width=30 
    fill=none >

<animate 
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
   from="0" 
   to="-62.83" 
   dur="1s" 
   repeatCount="indefinite" />

</circle>
  </svg>
```

Comment: Ой тут столько можно напридумывать :))))))