# Адаптивные декоративные черточки у заголовка

Tags: html, css

Есть заголовок, различного содержания, с декоративными черточками по бокам:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.title span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

h2.title span {
  display: inline;
}

.title span:before, 
.title span:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 42px;
    background: red;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.title span:before {
    right: 100%;
}

.title span:after {
    left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">
  <span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
</h1>
  
<h2 class="title">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</h2>
```

Проблема возникает на мобильных разрешениях. Пробую и `inline-block` и `inline`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:** как максимально приблизить черточки к тексту (независимо от содержания и длины слов) на мобильных разрешения?

Comment: display: flex, grid ?

Comment: Или есть причина почему они не используются?

Comment: @Hamster Привет! Вдруг не видела, на всякий случай [Новогодний конкурс 2020!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1061127/28748) По твоему пожеланию выбрал картинку с тёмным фоном, чтобы фейерверки хорошо смотрелись

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, спасибо!!! Не видела, времени и настроения совсем нет!))))

Comment: @HamSter А создать себе настроение, вопреки всему? На всякий случай, вдруг до праздника не увидимся. Всего тебе самого хорошего, пусть сбудутся все твои, даже самые дерзкие мечты в Новом 2020 Году!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
h1,
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: cursive;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  min-width: 42px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Lorem ipsum.</span>
</h1>

<h2>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor.</span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Похоже идеальный вариант, спасибо!

Comment: Можно и span убрать, потому что непонятно, для чего он там вообще https://jsfiddle.net/f928y6he/